# Не могу получить Uri изображения

Tags: android, firebase

Ребята, что я делаю не так?
В данном коде я загружаю картинку в Firebase Storage и после пытаюсь отобразить её. Но почему-то не работает отображение картинки. Загружать оно загружает на Storage,а вот отображать не хочет. Может Uri не правильно берётся?
Так же у меня почему-то подчёркивается красной линией вот эта строчка:

```
downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
```

Что здесь не так?

```
public class EditProfile extends Fragment{
    private static final int GALLERY_INTENT=2;
    private EditText editProfileName;
    private EditText editProfilePhone;
    private EditText editProfileNick;
    private ImageView image;
    private Uri downloadUrl;
    private Button saveBtn;
    private final int LENGTH = 1000;
    private FirebaseUser user;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    public EditProfile() {
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_edit_profile, container, false);
        image=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.edit_profile_photo);
        user= FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        editProfileName=(EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.edit_profile_name);
        editProfilePhone=(EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.edit_profile_phone);
        saveBtn=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.edit_profile_save);
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
        saveBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                chageProfile();
            }
        });
        image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setImage();
            }
        });
        return v;
    }

    public void setImage(){

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);

        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

        startActivityForResult(intent,GALLERY_INTENT);
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode==GALLERY_INTENT && resultCode==RESULT_OK){

            progressDialog.setTitle("Uploading");
            progressDialog.show();
            Uri uri = data.getData();
            StorageReference storageReference=FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
            StorageReference file=storageReference.child(user.getUid()+"/photo.jpg");
            file.putFile(uri)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                            // Get a URL to the uploaded content
                            downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                            UserProfileChangeRequest profileUpdates = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
                                    .setPhotoUri(downloadUrl)
                                    .build();
                            user.updateProfile(profileUpdates).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Фото добавлено",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                            // Handle unsuccessful uploads
                            // ...
                        }
                    });
        }
        image.setImageURI(user.getPhotoUrl());
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: По идее в storage можно сохранить либо контент либо url как текст.

Comment: что вы имеете в виду? Изображение загружается. Я просто не могу взять на него потом ссылку почему-то.

Comment: Я добавил скриншот,на котором видно загруженную картинку

Comment: Если у вас хранится контент (что вероятнее всего) - то вам нужно преобразовать его в data-протокол. Тогда картинка отобразится. Если хранится URL - то вам контент нужно присвоить в img.src

Comment: А можете показать как это делается,ибо я всё равно не очень понимаю вас.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

недавно столкнулся с такой же проблемой,нашел такой ответ:

```
@SuppressWarnings("VisibleForTests") Uri uri = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
downloadUrl = uri;
```

Comment: Я уже точно такой же ответ нашёл)